# Showing "#Error" in ssrs 2005 report

Tags: reporting-services, report, visual-studio-2005

In a field of my groupfooter section of a table I am writing This,

```
=FormatPercent(IIf((Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value+Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value)>0,(Fields!TotalCommittedTask_p1.Value+Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value)/(Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value+Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value),0))
```

It is not raising any build error. But when I preview the report it shows "#Error" in that field. What should be done?

Comment: You need to make sure both divider and devisable are non zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make sure both the divider value are non zero and also make sure the right conversion is done lots of time thee error raise in `ssrs` expression is due to the fact that conversion is not done.And also make sure the all the values in column are numeric.

```
 =FormatPercent(IIF((CInt(Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value)) > 0 ,    
  (CInt(Fields!TotalCommittedTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value))/(Cint(Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value))
  ,0))
```

Comment: Can you see what is error message in bottoms error window

Comment: ‘textbox80’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: can you do one thing create 1 separate columns in tablix temprorry and put `IIF((CInt(Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value)) > 0 ,    
  (CInt(Fields!TotalCommittedTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value))/(Cint(Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value))
  ,0)` in that box and let me know what happens And does any of the column contains null value ?

Comment: No, there is no any null value. and still showing #Error in the seperate columns. and the error msg : The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox95’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Ok so now both the values in two separate columns `CInt(Fields!TotalCommittedTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value)` in one column and `(Cint(Fields!TotalTask_p1.Value) + CInt(Fields!SuperVisorsCode.Value)` in another column. Sorry I can not reproduce the same issue at my end thats why you need narrow down the expression which is causing error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70612/discussion-between-mimi-and-coder-of-code).